# laravel webservice response returns null value

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

plz find the below code

Client

```
public function index()
{

    $username = Session::get('username');
    $password = Session::get('password');

    $url = url('/languagesService');

    $data = json_encode(array("username" => $username,"password" => $password));
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = CURL_EXEC($ch);
    $data = json_decode($response,true);
            return $data;//return $response tried both. 

}
```

Server

```
public function index()
{
$user = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );



    if ( Auth::attempt($user) ) {
        $data = languages::all();         
    }else {
        $data = array("invalid" => "Invalid username and password");
    }

    $response = Response::json($data,200);
    return $response;
       //return View::make("languages.index")->with("languages",$languages);
}
```

when accessing the server directly, it outputs the response in json format. but accessing via client, it responds nothing. Getting blank output. Tried trying with hard coded response, still the same blank output. Am i missing something tat is important?

Comment: Did you check your laravel logs or server logs to see the error?

Comment: getting the following error in laravel log. production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in D:\wamp\www\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:140

Comment: also, when i try with another server, it returns value.

Comment: It says it cant find the route. So either you have not copied the program across correctly - or there is another issue, perhaps with a case sensitive file name